# Send mail with "do not forward" restriction

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

When I try to update "do not forward" restriction mail with `oMail.Permission = olDoNotForward`, I am getting this error.

[image]

> We are not able to find the Information Rights Management template. Please contact your administrator.

The VBA function to send mail:

```
Function MailDraftSurvey(ByVal mailName As String, _
  ByVal mailFrom As String, ByVal mailTo As String, _
  ByVal mailCC As String, ByVal mailSubject As String, _
  ByVal SendMail As Boolean)

Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim msg As Object
Dim Mailpath As Variant
Dim i As Integer

Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Mailpath = ThisWorkbook.path & "\Mail Template\" & mailName

'to create a new Outlook item using object
'Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

Set oMail = objOL.CreateItemFromTemplate(Mailpath)
oMail.SentOnBehalfOfName = mailFrom
oMail.To = mailTo
oMail.CC = mailCC
oMail.Subject = mailSubject

oMail.Permission = olDoNotForward

'Check to Send or Display mail
If SendMail = True Then
    oMail.Send
Else
    oMail.Display
End If
End Function
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Error messages should be included in a Question as "plain text", not as images - keep this in mind when asking here, please. Also: Which line of code triggers the error? `CreateItemFromTemplate`? This error message indicates IRM protection has been applied to the template. You need to do what it says: contact the adminstrator (owner or creator of the template).

Comment: Sure. In future, I will error text instead of images. I am getting the error on "oMail.Permission = olDoNotForward" line. Is there any way to remove IRM Protection? If I create a new template will fix it?

Comment: Is IRM enabled on your Exchange mailbox? Can you send messages like that from Outlook when logged into the same profile?

Comment: How to check IRM enabled in mailbox ? I am able to send mail without "do not forward" restriction.

Comment: Earlier tried alternative way. Now found solution, first to display the mail then to enable 'Do Not Forward' restriction has worked.